# Which one is faster? on divide string

Tags: java, arrays, string

Which onr is faster and Why?

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), "", false);
String[] s = new String[st.countTokens()];
int a = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    s[a++] = st.nextToken();
```

or

```
String[] s = br.readLine().split("");
```

Comment: How many times are you doing this that any speed difference makes any observable change in performance?  I'd take the second option on the grounds of 'way more obvious code'.

Comment: Probably choice C. Which I would provide. But it depends on what you want with `s`.

Comment: ```char[] a = br.readLine().toCharArray()``` would be faster.

Comment: @ChengThao Why are you so sure? And who asked for a `char[]` anyway?

Comment: @shmosel What's a string of a single character?  A character.  Both solutions above would have to call substring for every character in the line each time creating a new String object.  ```toCharArray``` would simply return a copy of the array of the characters and would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Not all String implementations are backed by a char array.

Comment: After JDK9, the underlying implementation of string was changed from char array to byte array